# How to structure database tables?

Tags: database

I am planning a database.  It will track when a software program has been registered and log the information in the Registered table.

Two questions:

1:  where should i log invalid registration attempts. For example if the user enters the wrong registration information or if they try to register but they have used all of their licenses.  I want to remember this information but where do i put it?

I was thinking a separate FailiedRegiatration table or in general notifications table. What do you think?

2: Also if a user registers the same computer i want to allow them however i want to document that they reregistered the computer. Where should i store this information?

I was thinking making a DateRegiatered table that is linked to the Refistered table. That way for each successful registration i can keep track if someone reregisteres on the same computer.

Any comments are helpful as i think through this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you need to specifically act on failed registrations, or later activate it and make it a successful registration table, store it in a separate table.  If you only need to know about it, consider just storing the failure in a log table of some sort.
2. I think you want a separate table tracking user, and the machine registered on; that way, you know how many registrations a user performed, whether its 1, 2, or 10, etc.  Just a pointer table that points to user ID and the registration...

My two cents.

Comment: Yes another idea was to store all registrations in one table as you suggested. The only problem I can see is how to determine how many actual different computers that have been registered. If i limit registrations to 2 times and the user has registered 10 times but all on the same commuter then they should be allowed to register again but how do i know this with all of the duplicate registrations in the table?

Comment: You could store all registrations in that table, and add an IsFailed flag to denote the failed registrations.  You have to also figure out how to uniquely identify a machine; is this for a web site or a windows application?  The language of choice may have the ability to capture the machine name registered for, and then you can store this in the database too... or look at some other identity mechanism to identify the machine.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I prefer to use logs, rather than database tables, to record "events" that are suitable for logging, and your "failed registration" event definitely seems to fall under this category (the "dates of registration" information is more debatable from this point of view).

Of course, that does depend on having a good logging system (with log rotation, etc) *and* a good log-processing system too -- many hosting providers, for example, may not give you those, though they'll typically let you use a relational DB.

If that's the case (you can't rely on "good logging and log processing", but rather whatever you do need to persist must go s/where in the DB), then one or more "log-like tables" (more or less like you outline) are a kind-of-OK workaround (and it's hard to suggest better ones, especially without enough info about your deployment situation;-).

Comment: The only problem I can see with dumping it in a log table is that I would assume the log message would be the name email and key that was triednto register. And since his info is concatenated together in one log message column it would be more difficult to search.

Comment: @Steve, yep, logs are not made for searching, they're made for sequential "batch" processing that produces (off-line, later, "batch-like", periodically -- and especially without adding to the overall load involved in serving a request) whatever tables and summaries you need (ideally, if deployment constraints allow, on _another_ server not involved in the business of doing users' bidding;-).  A core principle of good server architecture: **serve fast** -- anything not directly involved in serving must _not_ be allowed to increase the latency, and logging & later processing is ideal for that.

Answer (score 0):

I think 2 tables would work. One table to track users (eg: id, username, serial, email), and one table to track registrations (id, foreign key to the users table, timestamp, record of success or failure, and some field to id the user's computer).

The second table would be your log table and have entries for successful initial reg, successful re-registration, and failed registration attempts. no?

Depending on how much information on the user's machine you have you can come up with various ways to ID if it is the same machine or not. This is a hard problem though.

Comment: Yeah I have most of the db design done but I am stuck on my questions above. My design has table for users programs orders orderItems registrations computers etc...